# CSS images loading extremely slow

Tags: css, optimization

I'm having difficulties with the following website :

http://ladaily.com/los-angeles

Seems like the rendering time of small images (less than 1KB) is extremely slow (over 2+ seconds).
Any idea on what can I do?

I know a big CSS file is a problem, but I can't do anything now to seperate it – 
any other idea why it occurs?

---

I think I got if figured , but from some reason images still loading very slow ,
Do you think it has anything with the server's configuration ?

Comment: how to compress CSS file size http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787789/any-recommendations-for-a-css-minifier

Comment: also make sure you're caching everything you can.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is css-sprite a good technique?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477332/is-css-sprite-a-good-technique)

Comment: I don't see any problem with this site. Do you use a recent browser / computer? Have you tried removing Google Maps from the page?

Comment: minified all JS + CSS , removed google maps API.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using Firefox, you could install a page-speed analyzing-addon like [yslow](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/yslow/) or [google page speed](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/speed/page-speed/) - this tells you how to optimize your website (sometimes not all of the optimizations are possible, but some are easy to do). this are some of the hints yslow gives for your site:

- This page has 27 external Javascript scripts. Try combining them into one.
- This page has 10 external stylesheets. Try combining them into one.
- This page has 41 external background images. Try combining them with CSS sprites.
- There are 76 static components without a far-future expiration date. (note by me: this might cause some browsers to not cache this css and js files and reload them on every page-load)

Also, your site is about 1143 KB in size to download if nothing is in the user's cache - that's *really* big, so you could try to minimize or compress the html, css and javascript (if you haven't done this already - but if your site is still about 1 MB after compression and minification it looks like there's something wrong...)

Comment: Most of the JS are external (google api , facebook .. etc..) , and the are a few JS and CSS running from my domain.
I believe the main problem is that there are ALOT of small images , or am I wrong ?

Comment: @Gal: Indeed, those are the “42 external background images”. See the answers on the [question I linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477332/is-css-sprite-a-good-technique) to see what you can do. That said, 27 external scripts is quite a lot. One of the problems is that each successive HTTP request generates some overhead.